# Visual Basic 2017 - DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

So I am having difficulty with my sub routines. I am creating an app to help with dungeon masters. Part of what my application will do is display several spreadsheets, in separate tabs, containing a list of items and details related to them. I want to reuse several my code instead of writing 20 or so nearly identical sub routines.

Here is my code, I am not sure how to solve my problem.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    loadExcel("C:\Users\secretUserName\source\repos\QUILLandDAGGER\QUILLandDAGGER\bin\Debug\recIntKnowl.xls",dgvRecEntKnowl)
End Sub

    Private Sub loadExcel(strFilename As String, dgvView As DataGridView)
    Try
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim Ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='strFileName';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        Ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyAdapter.Fill(Ds)
        dgvView.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: *"I am not sure how to solve my problem"*. What problem? Try describing what it is that specifically want help achieving.

Comment: What I am finding is it is not pulling up the excel sheet. The file is pointed to the correct location, despite I edited my name out of the location only to see it's actually part of my username o.0 oops

My guess is the file location, as directed in strFileName, isn't readable in the loadExcel sub routine.

I corrected the capital letter in the header. That didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Build the method like this:

```
Private Function LoadExcel(ByVal strFilename As String, Optional ByVal SheetName As String = "Sheet1$") As DataTable
    Dim SQL As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & SheetName & "]"

    Dim result As New DataTable
    Using MyConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(), _
          MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQL, MyConnection)
        MyConnection.Open()
        Using reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
           result.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

There are numerous improvements in this new code, both great and small. The most important are adding `Using` blocks, separating the data access from the UI, and designing functions that accept input in order to return a result.

Call it like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        dgvRecEntKnowl.DataSource = LoadExcel("C:\Users\secretUserName\source\repos\QUILLandDAGGER\QUILLandDAGGER\bin\Debug\recIntKnowl.xls.xls")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

As to whether this will actually fix anything... that depends on the problem you're having, which *wasn't included in the posted question.*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for failing to post my problem. I actually didn't know directly where my problem was and I've spent hours trying to find that.

My first problem was passing the string that contains directly to the file. It's poorly pointing to the file, which I'll resolve and have it point to a sub directory at a later point.

My second problem was with a specific line and I resolved that.

```
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\seidl\source\repos\QUILLandDAGGER\QUILLandDAGGER\bin\Debug\detect.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
```

This line of code was my original text and it worked.

```
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='strFileName';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
```

Was what I tried and it didn't work. I even removed the ' that surrounded the text and it didn't work.

So it finally clicked with me, to try something I used in Java when writing strings of texts and I needed variables in my lines of text. +

```
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + strFileName + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
```

This ended up working like a charm. I am guessing that OleDbConnection takes in a long string of characters and breaks down the string to read in what is needed. I could be wrong but this is incredibly interesting! It only took a many hours to finally see this.

Joel, I will investigate what you replied with and try and clean up my code. Thank you!

Comment: Use `&` for string concatenation.